# Spring Security - Access Exception saved by Authentication Failure Handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I implemented Spring Security, and a custom Authentication Failure Handler, which I use the inherited method [saveException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html#saveException-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException-) which the Documentation says

> Caches the AuthenticationException for use in view rendering.

Which would be perfect for me. This is what I want, I want to access the Exception saved by the Authentication Failure Handler in the frontEnd, i.e. I want to access in the bean that made the call to Spring Security.

My ControllerBean has this piece of code:

```
    public void login() throws ServletException, IOException {
    final ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest()).getRequestDispatcher("/login");
    dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();       
}
```

Which it makes the call to my CustomAuthenticationProvider, and then if it throws an exception, my CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler catches it and has the following code:

```
    @Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (exception instanceof FirstExternalLoginException) {
        setAllowSessionCreation(true);
        saveException(request, exception);
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/externalRegister.jsf");
    }
}
```

So when this piece of code finishes, it comes back to the line:

```
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Of the controller bean. How can I access the saved exception? I have been digging around the ExternalContext but have never found any AuthenticationException (or my custom exception, which extends the AuthenticationException)

Comment: On an authentication exception, you usually should not provide any detailed information, regarding security concerns. I would simply show "Bad authentication" on the front end. Otherwise, one can figure out which accounts exist and start brute forcing them.

Comment: The problem is I'm not using as a BadAuthentication. The case is this: My application has 2 ways of authentication, my internal AD, and an external Authentication engine, belonging to another organization. When it is the first time authenticating with the external engine, I need to register the user's information in my application, so I take him to another page, which is the /externalRegister.jsf. Now I don't want to give the FrontEnd a valid Authentication object, and redirect to external register, because the app would be accessible when he is not registered

Comment: Hence the FirstExternalLoginException, which has the required informations to register the user. I know the requirements are not easy to fulfill, but it is how the client wants.